# Automate IE print dialog box without using SendKeys

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to control the IE browser print dialog box in VBA without using SendKeys?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm new, now I'll get acquainted with the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, by using the InternetExplorer object's ExecWB method (see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752087(v=vs.85).aspx) for details).

After adding a reference to the *Microsoft Internet Controls* library to your project, the following example should get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintWebPage()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com/"
    ie.Visible = 1

    'Wait for page to finish loading
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

    MsgBox "Done printing.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's what I need! Tell me please, is it possible to check whether the IE browser print dialog box is already open with the help of the OLECMDID_PRINT command? For example, can I check whether the user opened the browser's print dialog box?